# How do you save game data when playing a Unity webGl game on a mobile browser?

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, unity-webgl

My Unity WebGL game runs on the mobile web browser after heavily optimizing the Audio and texture data. Saving the game data works fine on the desktop environment. But when I play the same game on a mobile browser, there seems to be no saving of game data anywhere. My code to save and load data locally is given below.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using UnityEngine;

public class DataAccess
{
    [DllImport ( "__Internal" )]
    private static extern void SyncFiles ( );

    [DllImport ( "__Internal" )]
    private static extern void WindowAlert ( string message );

    public static void Save ( Stats stats )
    {
        string dataPath = string.Format ( "{0}/Stats.dat", Application.persistentDataPath );
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter ( );
        FileStream fileStream;

        try
        {
            if ( File.Exists ( dataPath ) )
            {
                File.WriteAllText ( dataPath, string.Empty );
                fileStream = File.Open ( dataPath, FileMode.Open );
            }
            else
            {
                fileStream = File.Create ( dataPath );
            }

            binaryFormatter.Serialize ( fileStream, stats );
            fileStream.Close ( );

            if ( Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WebGLPlayer )
            {
                SyncFiles ( );
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            PlatformSafeMessage ( "Failed to Save: " + e.Message );
        }
    }

    public static Stats Load (Stats stats )
    {
        //Stats stats = null;
        string dataPath = string.Format ( "{0}/Stats.dat", Application.persistentDataPath );

        try
        {
            if ( File.Exists ( dataPath ) )
            {
                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter ( );
                FileStream fileStream = File.Open ( dataPath, FileMode.Open );

                stats = ( Stats ) binaryFormatter.Deserialize ( fileStream );
                fileStream.Close ( );
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            PlatformSafeMessage ( "Failed to Load: " + e.Message );
        }

        return stats;
    }

    private static void PlatformSafeMessage ( string message )
    {
        if ( Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WebGLPlayer )
        {
            WindowAlert ( message );
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log ( message );
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know whether this can be done, if so how?

Comment: When you say webGL vs. Desktop do you mean it works in a standalone build? In editor? In webGL on a desktop browser? I'd also attach your current save code to help clarify what you are doing.

Comment: Also what is your goal? Unity WebGL is not support on [mobile](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-browsercompatibility.html).

Comment: For clients I've used Babylon JS and Unity as the toolkit framework for mobile browser games: https://doc.babylonjs.com/extensions/Unity/Intro

Comment: @TEEBQNE, The WebGl game was built and uploaded to the server. When we play the game on a web browser on a Computer, it  works perfectly. Data is saved locally without a hassle. The moment the same game is played on a web browser on a mobile platform, the game plays BUT NO DATA IS SAVED LOCALLY.  My question above is how to save data locally when played on a mobile browser.

Answer (score 5):

Tell whoever your client is

> Note that Unity WebGL content is not currently supported on mobile
> devices

Taken directly from [`Unity Docs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-browsercompatibility.html). What they want is impossible. For the few devices that it does work, performance will most likely suffer and most functionality will not work as intended.

To answer how to save on webGL, if you implement a generic save / load solution using [`Application.PersistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html), the data will be saved at the location `/idbfs/<md5 hash of data path>`. It will allow data to be persistent through multiple sessions. It *might* work on mobile, but, again, would highly recommend you not do this. If you want mobile game, make a mobile game. The other option is to not use Unity.

Answer (score 1):

It would be beneficial to covert the webGL game into an app as playing on a mobile browser is slow and users may receive input lag.

Comment: Yes but this is what the client wants. The Game works but can't save data.

Comment: You could use Local Storage.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: could you kindly elaborate as to how this can be done in c#?

Answer (score 0):

You can call javascript functions from C#, in order to use the local storage for example. You have to add them (the scripts) in a "Plugins" folder with .jslib extension. More details here: [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html).
I have not tested this on mobile devices but I see no reason why this should not work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer though it's 11 months later. We scrapped the project due to this problem, but I will definitely keep this in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Man save yourself the pain and just use playfab

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Faced with a similar problem. I found a strange solution. If you save the data and then reload the scene, the progress is saved. But if you save the progress and don't reload the scene and then reload the page in the browser, then the progress won't be saved. It's all about saving progress locally on the device. However, if you save the progress to the server, then there is no such strange behavior

Comment: I gave up doing the project n Unity because of this issue. The client wanted the game to run in the browser only. Which version of Unity are you using?